# Different types of Users with simplemembership in ASP.NET EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, usertype

In my app I want to have two different types of users. This types differ not only in role but also in attributes. I am using simpleMembership for userManagement and I want to ask what's the best way or practise to create data model for my situation in EF using code first. I was thinking about creating two another tables UsersType1 and UsersType2 which will have one to one relationship with table userProfiles so in the model I would have:

```
public class UserType1{
    attr1
    attr2
    ....
    public int userProfileID {get; set;}
    public virtual UserProfile userProfile {get; set;}
}
```

And same way for table UserType2.

I want to ask if this is a good way to go and if so, how should I modify userProfiles table to be able to access UserType1 and UserType2 through userprofile in code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Roles" to group users of the same type. Then use a custom table with the roleid as key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunetely I am not sure if it solves my problem, or I do not see how. I know how to group users by Roles, but the thing is that every type of user has different attributes so can you give me more specific explanation please. Tahnk you.

Comment: use a property table then : (userid, propertyid, propertyvalue). Each user can have N properties, N depending of the user's role. See wordpress sql schema.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use [inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx), so UserType1 would inherit from UserProfile.

```
public class UserType1 : UserProfile
{
    attr1
    attr2
}
```

and when you fetch the UserProfile from the database you should be able to cast it to a UserType1 to access the attributes.